# Displaying Two Different Languages Content in Same Drupal Multilingual Site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, internationalization

We're building a Drupal 7 website that has Multilingual content for a dozen different languages. This has been pretty straight-forward to implement.

We have run into a weird scenario though, so any insight is much appreciated:

English is the default language. Another "language" option is Australia which should also display English content. In addition to displaying English content, there is also content that is unique to the Australian version of the site that should be displayed. For example:

**Australian Website**

- Home (English)
- About (English)
- Products (English)

  - Product One (English)
  - Product Two (Australian)
  - Product Three (English)
- Resources (English)
- Contact (Australian)

Is there a way with the i18n module in Drupal to have a certain "language" (Australian) display content for multiple languages - English and Australian?

Happy to provide any additional details. Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of multi lingual site is basically having 2 sites under one domain. One set of pages is on one language, other on other language. Then you pair one language page with other language page so the language switcher would know what page to open when you change the language.

But, from I saw in your question your site is not like that. You have 2 languages under the same "language domain". You have pages in different language in the same menu and no language switcher. If I guessed well I would say that you don't see multi lingual site at all. Just keep it in one language, speaking from technical point of view and enter the content in the language you want. The language of content it self is totally irrelevant if you site acts like it's single language one - all pages in all languages under the same menus, no menu switcher and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @MilanG! So it is a multi-language site and there is a language switcher used to jump from language to language. For instance, there is Chinese and that site has all unique content translated to Chinese. The unique scenario I described above is that there is an Australian site that should display all English content (since they speak English), but there should also be some content that is unique to Australia that should be displayed as well. So do we need to clone all English content and add Austrialian content or can we make that site show both types of content?

Comment: So, if i.e. Chinese is fully treated as different language, as I explained above, then ok - you really have multilingual site. And if only content for English and Austraila is "mixed" together (no lang. switching beteween 2 of them, they can belong to same menu..) then those 2 language should be treated as single language IMHO. Sorry, didn't get the last part of your post about cloning and content types. :(

Comment: It is a multilingual site - there are 13 different languages and those sites all have unique translated content on them, so we're all good there. However, there are an additional 5 "languages" we need to account for - hence my example of Australia. Australia speaks English so we'd like it to display English content, but there is also content that is unique to Australia (which can't display on the English site). This is why I'm curious if we can define that a specific language (Australia) can display multiple types of language content (English and Australian). Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Of course that you can add new one. From admin menu go to: Configuration -> Regional and language -> Languages -> Add Language ...if that's the question.

Comment: Well, I understand that would be how to add a language that doesn't exist - like Australian. But is there a way I can tell Drupal that when that custom language is selected that the site should show both English AND Australian content?